# Mobiles, HTML, CSS (& laziness)

Tags: html, css, mobile

With regards to mobile websites on smartphones;

Assuming that:

- HTML code is rarely a huge amount of data
- Compressed JS files are not so heavy
- Images are often loaded via CSS (at least could always)
- It's the same sequence (PHP + SQL = HTML) on server-side.
- It *seems* way faster to do this way and quite easy to maintain.

And even if:

- It's not graceful at all (hide Useless elements instead of generating a sharp and beautiful HTML code)
- Useless code is loaded and treated.
- Best practices for mobiles websites don't recommend to do this way.

Is it a good idea to rely only on different CSS to create a mobile version of a website? (Actually on different header templates, in order not to load useless JS)

Comment: Not sure what the down vote is for - there's a valid question in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a bad idea to serve HTML with elements that you know will be useless to your users.

- Small amounts of kb make a difference on mobile download speed.
- It means your CSS and Javscript need to be more complicated.
- You  users might see the content if the CSS or JS are slow loading.
- It will take more processing power (I think CSS styles will still be applied to the hidden elements).
- It's likely to be easier to manage on the server

**But** to answer the question "Is it a good idea to rely only on different CSS to create a mobile version of a website?";

**Yes if** you want your mobile users to have the same content as your large screen users. Which you probably should as this is normally what the users want.

**No if** you want to serve them different content.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for Belgium, I know a lot of people are still on Edge instead of 3G and loading a webpage takes some time. If we would have to load pages made your way, we would indeed be loading a lot of useless code, giving us quite a bad experience.
I'd suggest you stop being lazy and write your mobile websites the way they should be written. Think of your visitors and user experience; it honestly isn't that much of an effort.

I think you basically answered your own question already. Like BoltClock said, do what you want, but I sure wouldn't recommend doing things your way.